# Group of units of End($\mathbb{Z}/_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/_2) \cong S_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Consider the monoid End($\mathbb{Z}/_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/_2$) of endomorphisms of the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}/_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/_2$ under composition. Show that the group of units of End($\mathbb{Z}/_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/_2)$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_3$.

So far, I have:

The group of units of End($\mathbb{Z}/_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/_2$) contains all of the endomorphisms that are invertible. These are the endomorphims that do not map components to 0; thus, there are 6 elements in the group of units: 
    \begin{align*}
 \rho_1: & (x,y) \mapsto (x,y) & \rho_2: & (x,y) \mapsto (y,x)\\
 \rho_3: & (x,y) \mapsto (x, x+y) & \rho_4: & (x,y) \mapsto (x+y, x) \\
 \rho_5: & (x,y) \mapsto (y, x+y) & \rho_6: & (x,y) \mapsto (x+y, y) 
 \end{align*}
On the other hand, the symmetric group $S_3$ also has 6 elements: 
    \begin{align*}
 (1)(2)(3) & & (12)(3) & & (13)(2) & & (23)(1) & & (123) & & (321).
 \end{align*}

To show the isomorphism, I just need to exhibit a bijection. What do I need to do to define a bijection between these two groups? I can map the identity to the identity, so $\rho_1 \mapsto (1)(2)(3)$, but then can I just arbitrarily pair off the rest of the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this the other way round. An endomorphism is a unit if and only it is bijective; moreover $0$ is mapped to $0$.

So every unit in the endomorphism will certainly give you a bijective map from the nonzero elements of $Z/2 \oplus Z/2$ to itself, so a permutation of the nonzero elements, and there are 3. Conversely, this permutation of courses determines the endomorphism uniquely.

Thus you directly get an injective map from the unit endomorphisms into $S_3$. Since you have written down 6 unit elements in End thus suffices to show that the map is also surjective (in fact finding more than 3 would suffice).

Comment: So since I have 6 elements in the group of units of End($\mathbb{Z/2} \oplus \mathbb{Z/2}$) and 6 elements in $S_3$, if I map each element in End($\mathbb{Z/2} \oplus \mathbb{Z/2}$) to a unique element in $S_3$, is this sufficient to be a bijection?

Comment: @StephanieDeGraaf: To be a bijection? Yes. To be an isomorphism? Not necessarily.

Comment: Doesn't having a bijection imply that there is an isomorphism?

Comment: @StephanieDeGraaf yes this is sufficient to assert it is a bijection. An injective map from a finite set $A$ to a finite set $B$ is surjective if you know that the number of elements in A is at least as large as the number of elements in B. Yet note that as mentioned in another comment you need to make sure that it is additionally a homomorphism to have shown it is an isomorphism, as an isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism. We did show it is a homomorphism in the first part. So, it is *at that point* sufficient to show it is bijective to get it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

A unit in the ring of endomorphisms of an abelian group is an automorphism. The automorphisms of the Klein four group permute the three nontrivial elements, and are determined by such.

Comment: This argument is not complete. The same would be true for $(Z/p)^r$ for any prime p, and r. but the group is not isomorphic to $S_{p^r -1}$ in general. One needs to assert in addition that each permutation of the nonzero elements is an endomorphism (when extended to 0).

Comment: @quid Correct. ${}$