# Writing down elements using cycle notation.

Tags: group-theory, matrices, symmetric-groups, abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

I have $GL_2({\Bbb{Z}}_2)$ in which ${\Bbb{Z}}_2$ consists of the integers $\{0,1\}$.

We observe that $|M_2({\Bbb{Z}}_2)|=2^4$.

Now let's define Y to be the set of all non-zero elements of ${\Bbb{Z}}_2\times {\Bbb{Z}}_2$

$Y = [y_1,y_2,y_3]$

Where:

$$
      y1=  \begin{pmatrix}           
1\\
0\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
y2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
y3= \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Observe that $GL_2({\Bbb{Z}}_2)$ acts on Y via the function $GL_2({\Bbb{Z}}_2)\times Y\to Y$ given by  $(C,y)\mapsto C_y$ where $C_y$ denotes the products of the matrices.

Consider $\gamma:GL_2({\Bbb{Z}}_2)\to S_3$ corresponding to this action.

Here, $Y\mapsto\{1,2,3\}$ by $y\mapsto i$, we identify $S_y$ with the symmetric group $S_3$

To start, I found the elements of $GL_2({\Bbb{Z}}_2)$ which contains $6$ elements which are $2\times 2$ matrices with determinants of non-zero.

I am then told to write down for each $C\in GL_2({\Bbb{Z}}_2)$, the element of $\gamma(C)$ of $S_3$ in which I have to write down as cycle notation.

How am I supposed to do this?

And then next, I am to explain why $\gamma$ is an isomorphism from the group $GL_2({\Bbb{Z}}_2)$ onto the group $S_3$.

My explanation for this is that there exists two elements of the group in which it shows non-abelian and we know that $S_3$ is non-abelian, therefore isomorphism.

I feel as is if my explanation isn't enough, could someone also elaborate? Or am I right?

Thank you!

Comment: This might not exactly answer you question but the following question is quite similar and you might be able to resolve your problem by studying it http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019422/group-of-units-of-end-mathbbz-2-oplus-mathbbz-2-cong-s-3

Comment: Your set is $GL_2({\Bbb{Z}}_2)=\{1\!\!1,a,b,ab,ab^2,b^2\}$,
where
$$1\!\!1=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{array}\right)\ ,\ a=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
0&1
\end{array}\right)\ ,\
b=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
1&1
\end{array}\right),$$

$$ab=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
1&1
\end{array}\right)\ ,\ ab^2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{array}\right)\ ,\
b^2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
1&0
\end{array}\right),$$
which can discovered by brute force among the $16$ possibilities.

Comment: You're supposed to explain why γ is a homomorphism, i.e. you have to check $\gamma(AB)=\gamma(A)\gamma(B)$ for each pair $(A,B)$ of elements of $\mathop{\mathrm{GL}}\nolimits_2(\mathbf Z_2)$.